# Why am I getting black frames in this montage image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function [filterResponses] = extractFilterResponses(img, filterBank)
% Extract filter responses for the given image.
% Inputs: 
%   img:                a 3-channel RGB image with width W and height H
%   filterBank:         a cell array of N filters
% Outputs:
%   filterResponses:    a W x H x N*3 matrix of filter responses

    if (~isa(img, 'double'))
        img = double(img);
    end
    if (size(img, 3) == 1)
        img = repmat(img, [1 1 3]);
    end
    img = img./255;

    [L, a, b] = RGB2Lab(img(:, :, 1), img(:, :, 2), img(:, :, 3));
    filterResponses = zeros(size(img,1), size(img, 2), length(filterBank)*3);

    for k = 1:length(filterBank)

        L = imfilter(L, filterBank{k}, 'same', 'conv', 'replicate');
        filterResponses(:, :, k*3-2) = L;

        a = imfilter(a, filterBank{k}, 'same', 'conv', 'replicate');
        filterResponses(:, :, k*3-1) = a;

        b = imfilter(b, filterBank{k}, 'same', 'conv', 'replicate');
        filterResponses(:, :, k*3) = b;

    end

end
```

The above function applies one filter at a time from a set of 20 filters on each of the L*a*b layers of the given RGB image.

The following script is used to execute the function:

```
img = imread('sun_advbapyfkehgemjf.jpg');
filterBank = createFilterBank();
filteredImg = extractFilterResponses(img, filterBank);
filteredImgCell = cell(20,1);
for k = 1:length(filterBank)

    filteredImgCell{k} = cat(3, filteredImg(:, :, k*3-2), filteredImg(:, :, k*3-1), ...
                             filteredImg(:, :, k*3));
    filteredImgCell{k} = repmat(filteredImgCell{k}, [1 1 1 1]);
end

montage(cat(4, filteredImgCell{:}), 'size', [4 5]);
```

This script concatenates the L*a*b layers from the matrix `filterResponses` and then repmats the image to add a fourth dimension to be used in the montage function and gets stored in a cell. The cell is used in the montage function.

The output I am getting is as follows:

[image]

Why do the rest of the frames appear black? I know they are there cause if I multiply each image with say 10, I can see a few more frames. So, must be something to do with normalization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible issues:

- You are adding the filters *sequentially* to the `Lab` components, such that at iteration `k` you have applied *all* of the filters from `1` to `k` to them. This is going to continuously reduce the amplitude of your image values, causing them to become small enough that, when added to a montage, the smaller-value images appear to have very little dynamic range and just show up as black.

  I'm guessing you want to apply *just* filter `k` at iteration `k`, as opposed to all previous ones. If so, you should change your loop code to the following:

  ```
  for k = 1:length(filterBank)

    Lk = imfilter(L, filterBank{k}, 'same', 'conv', 'replicate');
    filterResponses(:, :, k*3-2) = Lk;

    ak = imfilter(a, filterBank{k}, 'same', 'conv', 'replicate');
    filterResponses(:, :, k*3-1) = ak;

    bk = imfilter(b, filterBank{k}, 'same', 'conv', 'replicate');
    filterResponses(:, :, k*3) = bk;

  end
  ```
- Without knowing what the exact input image is, I see a potential problem with this particular line that scales the image values:

  ```
  img = img./255;
  ```

  You aren't checking the range of values in the input first. If the input image is *already* scaled from 0 to 1, this will reduce the maximum amplitude to a value much smaller than 1. As above, repeated applications of your filters could cause the values to become small enough that, when added to a montage, the smaller-value images appear to have very little dynamic range and just show up as black.

  I'd suggest checking the range of the input image and scaling based on that. One option is to scale the image by its own maximum value to give a resulting range of 0 to 1:

  ```
  img = img./max(img(:));
  ```

Comment: It was probably the first case, but I corrected both the cases. Thank you! :)